# Microsoft Unified Service Desk (USD) 3.0 Custom Layout

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, unified-service-desk

When trying to create a CustomLayout for Microsoft Unified Service Desk (USD) 3.0 I get the error:

Error   1

> Cannot create an instance of "PanelLayoutBase".   c:\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\LayoutSolution\MyPanelLayout\CustomLayout.xaml  1   10  MyPanelLayout

I am using Visual Studio 2013
Latest version of the SDK

Comment: Does the project build?

Comment: Rebuild All: 1 succeeded

Answer (score 0):

Two possible fixes:

1. Dig into the exception details.  Determine the missing reference and add it manually.
2. Update NuGet packages.  XAML designer exceptions from v8.0 - 8.2 appear to have been resolved with SDK v9.0.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to go back to the USD 2.0 templates and DLL files.  Once I did this everything worked in USD 3.0.